# SSAS corrupt string store data file for one of the table columns error

Tags: ssas, dbcc

I'm getting error on SSAS when redeploy the project. The error is;

The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Error happened while loading table data. Possible cause is: corrupt string store data file for one of the table columns.Error happened while loading table data.A duplicate value has been detected in the Unique Value store associated with the dictionary.Database consistency checks (DBCC) failed while checking the data segments.Error happened while loading table '', file '1245.H$Countries (437294994)$Country (437295007).POS_TO_ID.0.idf'.Database consistency checks (DBCC) failed while checking the data segments.Error happened while loading table '', file '1245.H$Countries (437294994)$City ....

I checked the table Countries but there is no duplicated data.

Is there anybody who can help please?

Answer (score 1):

As the error implies, the model has some corrupted data (not to be confused with duplicated data).

Microsoft has some resolutions for there kinds of errors here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/database-consistency-checker-dbcc-for-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#common-resolutions-for-error-conditions

TL:DR:

> Depending on the error, the recommended resolution is to either
> reprocess an object, delete and redeploy a solution, or restore the
> database.